# Service to Service Authentication in Azure Data Lake Store using .NET SDK

Tags: azure-data-lake

I am trying to access this Service to Service 
Service-to-service authentication with client secret and certificate (trying with both) but no one working for me.
I am trying to create directory on Data lake store but that given code is not working.
It's not even giving any error so i can identify it.
I have followed all the steps mentioned in this page but not able to create directory on data lake store.
I have also tried File upload code but that is also not working.
End user Authentication is working fine.
So please suggest how can i achieve it.
Thanks!
Rajni

Comment: Could you share any info you have regarding the failure? The code you're using, and the behavior the code is exhibiting that leads you to know there's a problem? Here's the article we recommend; see either of the "service-to-service authentication" sections: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-net-sdk#authentication

Comment: Hi Matt, I have resolved my issue. There was some permission level issue. I need to set folder permission on root level and it resolved my issue. Thanks for your concern. I have One new issue. Actually i want to upload on folder (containing sub folders and files) to data lake store. DO yo have any idea about it? How can i achieve this? Simple file upload is working fine. But i want to do it for multiple.

Comment: If you're using the latest Data Lake Store SDK package for .NET, then it's as easy as: `client.FileSystem.UploadFolder("adlsAccountName", @"C:\my\sourcePath", @"/my/destinationPath/", recurse: true);`. There are also ways to do this in PowerShell/CLI, and other SDKs.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for your reply. I need to upload large amount of images (around 10,000) to data lake store. It's working fine but performance is very slow. Can you please suggest me any solution to upload these files fast as data could be in GB's. Please suggest me on this.

Comment: Hi Matt, I also tried your above mentioned code client.FileSystem.UploadFolder("adlsAccountName", @"C:\my\sourcePath", @"/my/destinationPath/", recurse: true);

Comment: Hi Matt, I also tried your above mentioned code client.FileSystem.UploadFolder("adlsAccountName", @"C:\my\sourcePath", @"/my/destinationPath/", recurse: true); Can you please suggest what is the latest version of Data Lake Store SDK package for .NET. I am using Microsoft.Azure.Management.dataLake.STore 1.0.4 version.Store uploader is of 1.0.1 version. Do we have any other update on it. Actually i am not able to find any updated version on it, but function 'UploadFolder' is not available in this version.

Comment: Hi Rajni, the latest version of Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store is 2.1.2-preview, and this version has the UploadFolder command. Here's more information: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store/2.1.2-preview

Comment: Hi Matt, Many Thanks for your all help. Actually i am new in Data lake store and its .net SDK but you really helped me on this which is appreciable :) Isrecurcive function is also available in UploadParameters and i set it as true it's also working fine and your above mentioned code is also working great :) Matt Can you please also help me in more item as i mentioned in my above thread. I need to upload huge data(upto 1 GB) and i am trying to upload these files. But while uploading such huge data it taking so much time around 45 mins. Can you please suggest any way to improve its performance?

Comment: Or is there any other out of box feature to ingest images (specifically) into ADLS. I tried Event hub but this seems to be for messages only. Azure Data factory seems to be working for SQL Data type of ingesting.

Comment: Happy to help! :) Both options you're looking at allow you to set some optional parameters to configure your upload, out of the box. For example, UploadFolder lets you set `perFileThreadCount`, which controls the number of threads that run per file. If your files are < 1 GB each, then you'll want to keep this as low as possible. There's also `concurrentFileCount`, which controls the number of files that get uploaded in parallel. Consider the resources available to your app, try out different values, and you should arrive at values that best utilize your available resources. I hope this helps!

Comment: As an alternative, there's also an Azure PowerShell cmdlet, Import-AdlStoreItem, which does the same thing as (and uses) this .NET SDK method, if you're looking for something a bit more consumable for the ad-hoc or scripting scenario, versus the .NET application development scenario.

Comment: Hi Matt, I tried perFileThreadCount and concurrentFileCount parameters but its not working fine. It's taking same time as without using it. Please suggest me if i am missing any thing. Thanks