# Upload full folder on Data lake store uisng .net sdk

Tags: .net, azure, azure-data-lake

I want to upload a folder (containing files and sub folders) to Data lake store using .net SDK.
.net SDK is working fine for single file, but how can upload full folder to Data lake store.
Please suggest.
I have used foolowing code to upload single file on data lake store:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-net-sdk

Thanks
Rajni

Comment: Hi, Above mentioned issue is resolved and discussed on below link: 
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43656099/service-to-service-authentication-in-azure-data-lake-store-using-net-sdk?noredirect=1#comment74490557_43656099